# How to create a list of strings in python given the final value?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a list in python that will automatically fill each integer including zero between zero and a given final value.

For example,

```
#final input is given as
Nfinal= 10
```

Then, Ideally, a list will be automatically made with strings:

```
'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','9','10'
```

If this makes sense please help! Thank you.

Sorry if this post is trivial, I'm just never quite sure (yet) how to find what I need when it's not in my words. I'm getting better every day - so bear with me!

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list = [str(x) for x in range(0,Nfinal+1)]
```

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense, but why: Nfinal+1?

Comment: List comprehensions are a very useful way to generate/use lists. Have a read of [this tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 1):

```
Nfinal = 10
list = []
for i in range(Nfinal+1):
    list.append(str(i))
```